# Wrong default route on yocto system with tun-adapter

Tags: networking, vpn, ip, routing, yocto-project

I was able to build a yocto project image with support for tun adapter. Once a connection is established a ip route with **destination 0.0.0.0** and **gateway 0.0.0.0** is created and my internet connection is broken. My problem is, that I don't know who or what creates this rule. I'm sure, that the software, which establishes the connection does not create any routes (I am the developer). Has anyone an idea how to prevent this route?

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         U     0      0        0 VPN
0.0.0.0         192.168.178.1   0.0.0.0         UG    10     0        0 eth0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 VPN
192.168.178.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
192.168.255.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 VPN
```

Here is my /etc/network/interfaces script

```
# /etc/network/interfaces -- configuration file for ifup(8), ifdown(8)

# The loopback interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution: **connman** is installed on this yocto system. If I add by tun adapter to the blacklist of connman there are no problematic routes anymore.

**/etc/connman/main.conf**

```
[General]
AlowHostnameUpdates=false
NetworkInterfaceBlacklist=eth,wlan,VPN
```